# Need to remove username from Flow Screen invoked via LoginFlow

Tags: visual-workflow, customer-community, loginflow

I have a requirement which asks for verification code sent on email.

So to enter the code, I have created a  custom screen in the flow.
This flow is invoked

Everything  works fine.

However, I can see Username and Logout button, which I didn't add, and is standard.

Is it possible to remove this?

[image: Picture showing screen]